# Столько снегА или столько снегУ?

Tags: морфология

Знаю, что правильно "столько (чего? Р.п.) снега", а является ли нормой "столько снегу" или это ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба окончания корректны (см., например, «Русский орфографический словарь» РАН). При этом второе более характерно для устной речи. Но, подчёркиваю, ошибкой оно ни в коем случае не является.